# The Insertion Sort algorithm. What's happening step by step?

Tags: python, algorithm, insertion-sort

I'm a new data science student and I am trying to understand what exactly is happening inside the insertion sort algorithm.

Can anyone tell me what's happening step by step? It would be most appreciated.

Below is a code I wrote with some verbose so I could hopefully understand what was happening a little better but to no avail.

```
A = [4, 1, 7, 52, 10, 12]
B = [4, 1, 7, 52, 10, 12]


def InsertionSort(A):

    for j in range(1, len(A)):

        print("***************** LOOP", j, "*********************\n")

        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        print("i:", i, " |  A[i]:", A[i], " |  key:", key, "\n")
        print("IS i:", i, ">= 0 and", A[i], ">", key, "?", "\n")

        while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:

            print("TRUE:", i, ">= 0 and", A[i], ">", key, "\n")

            A[i + 1] = A[i]  # left cell switches places with right cell
            i = i - 1

        A[i + 1] = key

    print("\n\n")
    print("=================== END =====================")


InsertionSort(A)
print("A (not-sorted): ", B)
print("A (sorted): ", A)
```

I don't understand how it switches the numbers.

Comment: Try imagining you're sorting a deck of cards, or some such. You start with no cards in your hand. Then you pick up one card and put it in your hand. Then you pick up a second card, and insert it either *before* the first card, or *after*. Then you pick up a third card, and find the place it goes. Push all the remaining cards down one and put it into place. Then you pick up a fourth card...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike bubble sort, Insertion sort does not merely swap numbers (conceptually).

First, it stores the value at current index `j` in a variable `key`.

Then it starts at just previous index `i` of current index (`i = j - 1`), and traverses backwards (`i = i - 1`) towards the beginning. For each index, it compares value with `key` (`while i >= 0 and A[i] > key`). If value at `i` is more than `key`, it shifts the value one index forward (`A[i + 1] = A[i]`), until it finds a value equal or lower than `key`. When such value is found, `key` should come just after that in sorted array, so it places `key` at next index `i+1` (`A[i + 1] = key`). It repeats the same process for all elements and result is sorted array.

This will help more https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting?slide=8.

Comment: Both explaination and the link has made it clear for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) works by looking at each element in the array and moving it towards the beginning of the array until it's smaller than everything seen so far.

To do this, an outer loop considers each element in the array (skip element `0` because there's nothing to compare it with and you don't want to `IndexError`). The inner loop slides the element starting at the current `i` index leftward, comparing it against each previous element `j-1` in the array until the section of the array seen so far is sorted.

Your debug output relies too heavily on text and numbers rather than a visual of the array, which is all that's needed to see the algorithm in action. I also recommend using a slightly larger array size.

As an aside, I recommend sticking to Python `camel_case` [naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

If you play with this code and walk through the output step by step and I think you'll see what's going on:

```
a = [7, 3, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]

def insertion_sort(a):
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        j = i
        print("moving %d:" % a[j])

        while j > 0 and a[j-1] > a[j]:
            a[j-1], a[j] = a[j], a[j-1]
            j -= 1
            print(a)
            print(" " + "   " * j + "^---")

        print()

print("original: \n" + str(a) + "\n")
insertion_sort(a)
```

Output:

```
original: 
[7, 3, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]

moving 3:
[3, 7, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]
 ^---       

moving 6:
[3, 6, 7, 9, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]
    ^---

moving 9:

moving 4:
[3, 6, 7, 4, 9, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]
          ^---
[3, 6, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]
       ^---
[3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2]
    ^---

moving 5:
[3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 8, 0, 1, 2]
             ^---
[3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8, 0, 1, 2]
          ^---
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 0, 1, 2]
       ^---

moving 8:
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
                ^---

moving 0:
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9, 1, 2]
                   ^---
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2]
                ^---
[3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
             ^---
[3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
          ^---
[3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
       ^---
[3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
    ^---
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
 ^---

moving 1:
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 9, 2]
                      ^---
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 9, 2]
                   ^---
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 9, 2]
                ^---
[0, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
             ^---
[0, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
          ^---
[0, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
       ^---
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
    ^---

moving 2:
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9]
                         ^---
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9]
                      ^---
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9]
                   ^---
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                ^---
[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
             ^---
[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
          ^---
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
       ^---
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is ordering a given array. First it iterates over the elements of the array, starting from the second element:

```
for j in range(1, len(A)):
```

Then it compares element `j` (`key`) with element `j-1` (`A[i]`):

```
while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:
```

In case element `j-1` is bigger than element `j` it needs to swap them, so it does the swap:

```
A[i + 1] = A[i]
```

Now it needs to check if this is true also for element `j-2`, hence the while loop. Hope this helps a bit.